# Difference between th:with and th:if

Tags: thymeleaf

what is the difference between th:with and th:if in thymeleaf? Do I use th:if or th:with? I am not too sure of their difference.

I have tried to search for usage of th:with but there isn't much document around.

For example,

```html
<td>    
    <div th:with="${a given condition}">    <!--do I use th:if or th:with here?-->
        <span th:if="${}"></span>
        <span th:if="${}"></span>
    </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`th:with` is used to assign variables](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#local-variables).  It doesn't have anything to do with evaluating conditions, instead it's used to assign a value to a variable.  The sytnax looks like this:

```
<div th:with="firstPer=${persons[0]}">
```

[`th:if` and `th:unless` are used to evaluate conditions](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#conditional-evaluation) (to determine whether or not to show a block of html).

```
<div th:if="${user.isAdmin()} == false">
```